# problem YouTube channel with IE browser

Tags: asp.net, browser, youtube

I had youtube channel where I had for in my web site to display this videos from youtube channel .I did my code well but I had a problem with IE browser the sound continuous after I closed the player as you must let the player work after it finished ,So what I can Do?

Comment: You may start by showing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didnt reset either the object or embed container or something.

Thing is that internet explorer embeds flash differently.

You probably just deleted the content element so it became invisible but did not unset the flash media.

consider using this widely used javascript library to take care of all that for you:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/